# SQL Column Names from a Excel Sheet

Tags: sql, excel, ssms, sql-server-2014-express

Im using SSMS 2014 and SQL Server 2014. I need to change the column names at the end of a query result by using a excel file or table with the data.

After some SELECT statements and stuff i get a table with data for example

```
+---------+---------+------+
|  Col1   |  Col2   | Col3 |
+---------+---------+------+
| Value 1 | Value 2 |  123 |
| Value 2 | Value 2 |  456 |
| Value 3 | Value 3 |  789 |
+---------+---------+------+
```

And the table or excelfile

```
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+
| ID | ColName |  Language |  Addition |
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | Col1    |  D        |       123 |
|  2 | Col2    |  D        |       456 |
|  3 | Col3    |  D        |       789 |
|  4 | Col1    |  E        |       123 |
|  5 | Col2    |  E        |       456 |
|  6 | Col3    |  E        |       789 |
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

What i try to do is to get the addition value of each column and add it to the column name. It should only add the values with the specific `language. @setLang = 'D'`

```
Col1 + Addition
Col2 + Addition
Col3 + Addition

+-------------+-------------+---------+
|  Col1 123   |  Col2 456   | Col3789 |
+-------------+-------------+---------+
| Value 1     | Value 2     |  123    |
| Value 2     | Value 2     |  456    |
| Value 3     | Value 3     |  789    |
+-------------+-------------+---------+
```

I tried it over Information_Schema.Columns and filter with where table = 'resultTable' and Column_name = @cName. Maybe i need a loop to get each columnname.

Thanks for reading and trying to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i tried it again but now without the Excelfile. I made a CSV out of the Excelfile and insert it with Bulk to my created Table:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'CSVTest')
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE _DICTIONARY
( _TableName VARCHAR (20),
_ColumnName  VARCHAR  (20),
_Language    VARCHAR  (20),
_FieldShort  VARCHAR (50),
_FieldMid    VARCHAR (50),
_FieldLong   VARCHAR (50)
)
BULK
INSERT _DICTIONARY
FROM 'C:\_DICTIONARY.csv'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
END
```

After that i rename all Columns by using a Cursor

```
DECLARE @dic_tableName            as nvarchar(50),
        @dic_columnName           as nvarchar(50),
        @db_tableName              as nvarchar(50),
        @db_columnName            as nvarchar(50);


DECLARE C CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT _TableName, _ColumnName FROM _DICTIONARY
OPEN C;

FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @dic_tableName, @dic_columnName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS(SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @dic_tableName AND COLUMN_NAME = @dic_columnName)
BEGIN
  SET @db_tableName = @dic_tableName + '.' + @dic_columnName
  SET @db_columnName = @dic_tableName + '_' + @dic_columnName
  EXEC sp_rename @db_tableName, @db_columnName ,'COLUMN'
  FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @dic_tableName, @dic_columnName;
END
  ELSE
BEGIN
  FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @dic_tableName, @dic_columnName;
END
END

CLOSE C;
DEALLOCATE C;
```

Its doing its job.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go - it uses a table, not an excel file (but that seems to be an option in your question). I have made some temporary tables and filled them with your values, but you will obviously not need to do this. You will need to replace out the references to the `tempdb` with the name of the database where your tables are kept and the temp tables #Original and #ExcelInfo with your table names.

I have also used a temp table to add an 'Id IDENTITY(1,1)` Column to the table holding your original data. This is needed to keep the unpivot in check; if you can modify your table to include an Id, that will make things easier, but if not, you can insert into a temp table as I have done.

The script is shorter than it looks - the whole first bit is just setting up the example; the real answer starts at the line that declares your language variable.

```
/*
The script between the first two dividing lines of dashes is just used to set up the example. The bit you want is from
the "-- Test Variables --" line.
*/
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Original') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Original
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ExcelInfo') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ExcelInfo

CREATE TABLE #Original
( Col1  VARCHAR(50)
 ,Col2  VARCHAR(50)
 ,Col3  VARCHAR(50))
CREATE TABLE #ExcelInfo
( Id            INT IDENTITY(1,1)   NOT NULL
 ,ColName       VARCHAR(50)         NOT NULL
 ,[Language]    CHAR(1)             NOT NULL
 ,Addition      INT                 NOT NULL)

INSERT #Original
SELECT *
FROM
        (   SELECT 'Value 1' AS Col1,'Value 2' AS Col2  ,123 AS Col3
    UNION   SELECT 'Value 2'        ,'Value 2'          ,456
    UNION   SELECT 'Value 3'        ,'Value 3'          ,789)           AS This
ORDER BY Col1


INSERT #ExcelInfo (ColName,[Language],Addition)
SELECT *
FROM
        (   SELECT 'Col1' AS ColName, 'D' AS [Language], 123 AS Addition
    UNION   SELECT 'Col2','D',456
    UNION   SELECT 'Col3','D',789
    UNION   SELECT 'Col1','E',123
    UNION   SELECT 'Col2','E',456
    UNION   SELECT 'Col3','E',789)                                  AS This
ORDER BY [Language], Addition

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Test Variables --
DECLARE @SetLang CHAR(1) = 'D'
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- make the default empty, not null on our dynamic string, so it can be added to
DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

CREATE TABLE #OriginalColumns
( Id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
 ,Name VARCHAR(50))
CREATE TABLE #BasicResult
(Id INT NOT NULL, Name VARCHAR(50), Value VARCHAR(50))
-- If you can add an id column to your original table, this bit is unecessary - you can use yours in place of this table
CREATE TABLE #Original_WITH_Id
( Id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
 ,Col1  VARCHAR(50)
 ,Col2  VARCHAR(50)
 ,Col3  VARCHAR(50))

INSERT #Original_WITH_Id
SELECT * FROM #Original
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- List out the columns and put the list in a variable.
INSERT #OriginalColumns
SELECT QUOTENAME(Col.name)
FROM tempdb.sys.columns AS Col
WHERE Col.object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Original_WITH_Id')
-- we're not interested in the identity column at the moment
AND Col.name <> 'Id'
-- keep everything in the same order as they are listed on the table
ORDER BY Col.column_id

SELECT @Columns = @Columns + ',' + Name
FROM #OriginalColumns
-- clip off the leading comma
SELECT @Columns = SUBSTRING(@Columns,2,LEN(@Columns))

-- get a full list of everything, creating our new list of columns as we go, using the Id column to keep a mark on which
-- row each record originally came from
SET @SQL =
'INSERT #BasicResult
SELECT Id, New.Name, Value FROM
     (SELECT Id, Name, Value
      FROM #Original_WITH_Id
      UNPIVOT (Value FOR Name IN (' + @Columns + ')) Unpvt) AS Old
JOIN (SELECT ColName, CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),ColName) + '' '' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),Addition)  AS Name
      FROM #ExcelInfo
      WHERE [Language] = ''' + @SetLang + ''') AS New ON Old.Name = New.ColName'
PRINT @SQL
EXEC (@SQL)

-- now update our list of columns to be the new column headings
SET @Columns = ''
SELECT @Columns = @Columns + ',' + QUOTENAME(Name) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM #BasicResult) AS Names
SELECT @Columns = SUBSTRING(@Columns,2,LEN(@Columns))

-- pivout our results back out to their original format, but with the new column headings (include the Id if you want)
SET @SQL =
'SELECT /*Id,*/ ' + @Columns + '
 FROM
    (SELECT Id, Name,Value
     FROM #BasicResult) AS Up
     PIVOT (MAX(Value) FOR Name IN  (' + @Columns + ')) AS Pvt'

PRINT @SQL
EXEC (@SQL)

-- clean up --
DROP TABLE #OriginalColumns
DROP TABLE #BasicResult
```

Hope that helps! There may be a more efficient way to do this... I'm not sure.

Comment: Hey thank you for your help. To be honest i didnt try your code out so im not sure if its working or not. My solution is working with a cursor and its working with less code. What do you think?

Comment: Fair enough - if it works, it works! It is also good to avoid the dynamic SQL. The downside of a cursor is that the performance is not going to be good for large data sets. If you are only using a small data set and the performance is good then great!

Comment: Well yes you are right with the performance. But the CSV table has only ~3000 rows and it renames my columns in ~3 seconds which is good in my opinion. Thank you anyway!